if statement in htaccess
I'm using the following .htaccess to allow access to my website by IP address:
<Limit GET POST>
 Require all denied
 Require ip x.x.x.x
 Require ip y.y.y.y
</Limit>

I was wondering if it were possible to add an if statement so when a visitor adds a secret value like "?bypass=1" to the URL the IP check is skipped.

Why prevent access if you're going to allow bypassing restrictions?

@djdomi Just in case.

There are no reasonable information technology management practices in a business environment, in my humble opinion.

@djdomi The question does not include any details on the environment or even the use case. It seems purely a syntax question.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Check for the secret bypass parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} bypass=1
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the secret parameter is not present, apply IP restriction
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <RequireAll>
        Require ip x.x.x.x
        Require ip y.y.y.y
    </RequireAll>
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from x.x.x.x
    Allow from y.y.y.y
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

# Fallback if mod_rewrite is not available
<Limit GET POST>
    Require all denied
    Require ip x.x.x.x
    Require ip y.y.y.y
</Limit>


Thanks for your effort. mod_rewrite is available, but unfortunately your attempt doesn't work.
